# Check if parquet file exists using scala

Tags: azure, scala, databricks

Posting similar question, as the existing thread is very old. I am using the below code to check if the file exists at target_path or not. Though the file is present I am getting return value as 'false'. Am I missing on some settings?

```scala
val config = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(config)
var existCheck = fileSystem.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(target_path))
```

I also tried the below codes given in the site, but it is also returning 'false'

```scala
new java.io.File(target_path).isFile
scala.reflect.io.File(target_path).exists
```

target_path is having one delta_log and a parquet part file. Please help me to get the correct status.
(DBR-7.3 LTS, spark-3.0.1)

Comment: are you checking existence of the file inside folder? Or folder itself? Is your file/directory on mounted filesystem (`dbfs:/`), or you're using full URL, like `abfss://` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close :)

Below I use `listStatus` to give me back an array of status' of all of the files under `pathToFolder`, which would be the path to the folder containing the parquet file.

I then check the paths of each of the files under the folder too check for matches to `target_path`.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val sc: SparkContext = ???

val pathToFolder: String = ???
val pathToParquetFile: String = target_path

val config = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val src    = new Path(pathToFolder)
val fs     = src.getFileSystem(config)

val parquetFileExists: Boolean = fs
  .listStatus(src)
  .map(_.getPath.toString)
  .find(_ == pathToParquetFile)
  .isDefined
```